# iOS UIAutomation Simulator 5.0: The target application appears to have died

Tags: xcode, instruments, ios-ui-automation

I'm trying to use the record feature in `UIAutomation` that only works on Simulator 5.0.
When using `UIAutomation` on Simulator 4.3, it runs perfect.  When running my app from Xcode on Simulator 5.0 it runs perfect. This rules out the possibility that the app itself is crashing.

I tried resetting the simulator through `Reset Content and Settings`.   I tried selecting the target from the "Derived Data" folder of my app, or from the simulator Application folder, nothing worked.

Any ideas?

Comment: tried restarting your mac? solved some of my curious bugs (but in older xcode versions).

Comment: do you use any ios5 specific apis?

Comment: the recording feature exists only in iOS5 simulator

Comment: how exactly was this problem solved ?

Comment: it wasn't, i used http://www.gorillalogic.com/testing-tools/monkeytalk

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it happens that the old code is still alive.

1. Try to clean your project by clicking on `menu Product --> Clean` or `Command-Option-Shift-K`
2. `close x-code` and `clean data from ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` manually.